# Screen ON/OFF receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My application don't have any user interaction. I need to run some code when the phone goes to the `SCREEN OFF` or `SCREEN ON` state.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.testing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <receiver android:name=".ChekingReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**My receiver class**

```
public class ChekingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("received :"+intent.getAction());
}

}
```

But this is not working.Can Anybody find the mistake i am doing here ?